# Storing names in array and displaying them in alphabetical order

Tags: c#

Why does `richTextBox1.Text` not display the names when I run the code. I need to display the names in alphabetical order. Does this code not work because of `Array.Sort(nameArray);` or are the names themselves not being stored.

```
string[] nameArray = new string[5];

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxName1.Text = nameArray[0];
        textBoxName2.Text = nameArray[1];
        textBoxName3.Text = nameArray[2];
        textBoxName4.Text = nameArray[3];
        textBoxName5.Text = nameArray[4];   
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Array.Sort(nameArray);

        foreach(string s in nameArray)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += s + " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you collect items to that array? Are you sure, that textBoxName1.Text = nameArray[0]; shouldn't be like that: nameArray[0] = textBoxName1; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that help you

```
string[] nameArray = new string[5];

void CopyTextBoxesToArray()
{
    nameArray[0] = textBoxName1.Text;
    nameArray[1] = textBoxName2.Text;
    nameArray[2] = textBoxName3.Text;
    nameArray[3] = textBoxName4.Text;
    nameArray[4] = textBoxName5.Text;
}

private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CopyTextBoxesToArray();
    Array.Sort(nameArray);

    foreach(string s in nameArray)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += s + " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your array doesn't have any values try by adding values to your string array like below

```
string[] nameArray = new string[5]
    {
        "Egyptian",
        "Indian",
        "American",
        "Chinese",
        "Filipino",
    };
```

if you are trying to get array values from textbox you have to assign textbox value to Arrau

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nameArray[0] =textBoxName1.Text ;  
    }
```